# How to process data into 20Minute aggregates in Python

Tags: python, dataframe, aggregate

I have the folowing table

| TimeStamp | Name | Marks | Subject |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 00:00:02.969 | Chris | 70 | DK |
| 2022-01-01 00:00:04.467 | Chris | 75 | DK |
| 2022-01-01 00:00:05.965 | Mark | 80 | DK |
| 2022-01-01 00:00:08.962 | Cuban | 60 | DK |
| 2022-01-01 00:00:10.461 | Cuban | 58 | DK |

I want to aggregate the table for each column into 20minute aggregate which includes max, min, values

Expected output

| TimeStamp | Subject | Chris_Min | Chris_Max | Chris_STD | Mark_Min | Mark_Max | Mark_STD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 00:00:00.000 | DK | 70 | 75 |  |  |  |  |
| 2022-01-01 00:20:00.000 | DK | etc | etc |  |  |  |  |
| 2022-01-01 00:40:00.000 | DK | etc | etc |  |  |  |  |

I am having hard time aggregating the data into required output.
The agggregation should be dynamic so as to change to 10min or 30min.

I tried using bins to do it, but not getting the desired results.

Please Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the following:

```
rule = "10min"
result = (
    df.set_index("TimeStamp").groupby(["Name", "Subject"])
      .resample(rule)
      .agg(Min=("Marks", "min"), Max=("Marks", "max"), STD=("Marks", "std"))
      .unstack(0)
      .swaplevel(0, 1).reset_index()
)
```

- First setting `TimeStamp` as index, and grouping by `Subject` and `Name` to get the right chunks to work on.
- Then `.resampling()` the groups with the given frequency `rule`.
- Then aggregating the required stats by using `.agg()` with named tuples.
- Unstacking the first index level (`Name`) to get it in the columns.
- Swapping the remaining index levels to get the right order when finally resetting the index.

Result for the given sample:

```
      TimeStamp Subject   Min              Max                  STD               
Name                    Chris Cuban Mark Chris Cuban Mark     Chris     Cuban Mark
0    2022-01-01      DK    70    58   80    75    60   80  3.535534  1.414214  NaN
```

If you want the columns exactly like in your expected output then you could add the following

```
result = result[
    list(result.columns[:2]) + sorted(result.columns[2:], key=lambda c: c[1])
]
result.columns = [f"{lev1}_{lev0}" if lev1 else lev0 for lev0, lev1 in result.columns]
```

to get

```
   TimeStamp Subject  Chris_Min  Chris_Max  ...  Cuban_STD  Mark_Min  Mark_Max  Mark_STD
0 2022-01-01      DK         70         75  ...   1.414214        80        80       NaN
```

---

If you're getting the `TypeError: aggregate() missing 1 required positional argument...` error (the comment is gone), then it could be that you're working with an older Pandas version that can't deal with named tuples. You could try the following instead:

```
rule = "10min"
result = (
    df.set_index("TimeStamp").groupby(["Name", "Subject"])
      .resample(rule)
      .agg({"Marks": ["min", "max", "std"]})
      .droplevel(0, axis=1)
      .unstack(0)
      .swaplevel(0, 1).reset_index()
)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your table a pandas dataframe ?
If it's a pandas dataframe you can use resample:

```
# only if timestamp is not the index yet:
df = df.set_index('TimeStamp') 
# the important part, you can use any function in agg or some str for simple 
# functions like mean:
df = df.resample('10Min').agg('max','min') 
# only if you had to set index to timestamp and want to go back to normal index:
df = df.reset_index()
```

Edit to get second table in the function:

```
# choose aggregation function
agg_functions = ['min', 'max', 'std']
# set_index on time column, resample
resampled_df = df.set_index('TimeStamp').resample('10Min').agg(agg_functions)
# flatten multiindex
resampled_df.columns =  resampled_df.columns.map('_'.join)
# drop time column 
resampled_df = resampled_df.reset_index(drop=True)
# concatenate with original df
pd.concat([df, resampled_df], axis=1)
```

Comment: Any idea how to aggregate data to the desired output? 2nd table in the question?

Comment: I edited the answer, columns suffix will be std, max,min instead of STD, Max, Min as in your example, if you need to have this case-sensitive I have the code for that